# Training model doesn't work when implementing multilinear regression from scratch in python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

I managed to successfully implement multilinear regression using only numpy for Iris dataset. I wanted to do the same for
[boston houses data set](https://www.kaggle.com/c/boston-housing) but my model won't learn and I have no idea why.

```
import pandas as pd

# read data and split into test and training sets
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
data = (data - data.mean()) / data.std() # normalize data
split_data = np.random.rand(len(data)) < 0.8
train_data = data[split_data].round(5)
test_data = data[~split_data]

# create matrices 
input_features_train = train_data.drop(['ID', 'medv'], 1).values
output_feature_train = train_data.medv.values.reshape(-1, 1)
ones = np.ones([input_features_train.shape[0], 1])
input_features_train = np.concatenate((ones, input_features_train), 1)

weight = np.zeros([1, 14])


def computeCost(X, y, theta):
    summed = np.power(((X @ theta.T) - y), 2)
    return np.sum(summed) / (2 * len(X))


def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, iters, alpha):
    costs = np.zeros(iters)
    for i in range(iters):
        theta = theta - (alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(X * (X @ theta.T - y), 0)
        costs[i] = computeCost(X, y, theta)

    return theta, costs


learning_rate = 0.01
iterations = 100000

weights, cost = gradientDescent(input_features_train, output_feature_train, weight, iterations, learning_rate)
print("Weights: ", weights)
finalCost = computeCost(input_features_train, output_feature_train, weights)

# test 
input_features_test = test_data.drop(['ID', 'medv'], 1).values
output_feature_test = test_data.medv.values.reshape(-1, 1)
ones = np.ones([input_features_test.shape[0], 1])
input_features_test = np.concatenate((ones, input_features_test), 1)


def test_data(input_features, output_feature, weights):
    predictions = np.round(np.dot(input_features, weights.T))
    for i in range(len(output_feature)):
        predicted = predictions[i]
        success = predictions[i] == output_feature[i]
        print('For features: ', input_features[i], ' housing price should be ', output_feature[i])
        print("Predicted: %f" % predicted)
        print("Is success? ", success)
        print()


test_data(input_features_test, output_feature_test, weights)
predictions = np.round(np.dot(input_features_test, weights.T))
accuracy = (sum(predictions == output_feature_test) / float(len(output_feature_test)) * 100)[0]
print("Accuracy of the model is ", accuracy, "%  after ", iterations, "iterations")
```

example output goes as follow

```
Weights:  [[ 0.01465871 -0.11583742  0.17729105  0.01249782  0.09822299 -0.31249182
   0.25208063 -0.00937766 -0.48751822  0.46772537 -0.27637035 -0.1590125
   0.12926108 -0.48910136]]

For features:  [ 1.         -0.44852959 -0.47141352  0.09095532 -0.25240023  0.13793157
  0.46506236  0.03105118 -0.62153314 -0.98758424 -0.79769195  1.18594974
  0.37563165 -0.40259248]  housing price should be  [-0.04019949]
Predicted: 0.000000
Is success?  [False]
```

I tried even 10000000 iterations and still it fails all tests and has 0% accuracy. On iris data set I managed to get 100% with this model so I don't understand why it won't work.

I suspect it might be something with data normalization as without it I get `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  summed = np.power(((X @ theta.T) - y), 2)` error which I also don't know why is happening. 
Could you please point me in the right direction ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest you to use scikit learn for this. You can use SGD Regressor,or Cat Boost Regressor which have inbuilt support required for approaches like these.

The main motive behind this suggestion is using gradient descent manually may lead to some logical error which may go undetected.

Try to solve with scikit learn.That might help.